# Query/use the study overlay state inside code

Tags: overlay, pine-script

At the beginning of a study its overlay state is defined:

```
study("My title", overlay=true)
```

Is it possible to query/use that state inside the code?
I thought of building a more versatile indicator
and decide wether or not to plot something:

```
plotshape((overlay == true ? my_series1 : na), title="my shape", style=style=shape.diamond,...)
plot((overlay == false ? my_series2 : na),title="my line", style=plot.style_line,...)
```

The second plot could be for example an oscillating line, which is better plotted on a separate chart window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

However, you can use a bool input to decide whether to plot something or not.

```
study("My Script", overlay=false)
isPlotClose = input(title="Plot close?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

plot(series=isPlotClose ? close : na)
```